Serialized Object to JsonResponse return empty response using serializer service in Symfony 5 Controller
I use to add vue3 frontend content in a backend symfony 5,
I need to return a jsonResponse for sorting values in the front,
I did a Serializer Service to Serialize in Json an object which is from the Doctrine Repository,
The BDD callback is a type Grilles object,
So to have a Json from the object I use for Serializer,
Until that there's no problem, The Serializer service return correct Object but it's empty about the content...
I don't see anything about that, can you debugging me please ?
The SerializerService:
namespace App\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class SerializerService
{
    public function serialize()
    {

    $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    return $serializer;
    
    }
}

The Repository:
public function findOneInAllGrillesObj($email, $type): ?Grilles
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('g')
            ->andWhere('g.email = :email')
            ->andWhere('g.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('email', $email)
            ->setParameter('type', $type)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }

The controller:
/**
     *
     * @Route("/grilleADisplay", name= "grilleADisplay", methods={"GET","POST"})
     * IsGranted("ROLE_USER", message="vous devez vous connecter pour accéder à cette ressource")
     */
    public function jsonDisplayGrilleA(EntityManagerInterface $manager, SerializerService $serializer): JsonResponse
    {
        if(is_null($this->getUser())){
            $session=$request->getSession();
            $session->getFlashBag()->add("messageError" , "Vous devez être connecté pour accéder à cette ressource");
            return $this->redirectToRoute("login");
        }
        $type="A";
        $email=$this->getUser();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $grillesrepository = $em->getRepository(Grilles::class);
        $datas = $grillesrepository->findOneInAllGrillesObj($email, $type);
        //dd($datas);
        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($datas);
        //dd($jsonContent);
        dd(new JsonResponse($jsonContent));
        return new JsonResponse($jsonContent);
    }

The DD give:
GrillesController.php on line 81:
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer {#1144 ▼
  #encoder: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\ChainEncoder {#1158 ▶
    #encoders: array:2 [▶
      0 => Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder {#1149 ▶
        -defaultContext: array:7 [▶
          "as_collection" => false
          "decoder_ignored_node_types" => array:2 [▶
            0 => 7
            1 => 8
          ]
          "encoder_ignored_node_types" => []
          "load_options" => 2304
          "remove_empty_tags" => false
          "xml_root_node_name" => "response"
          "xml_type_cast_attributes" => true
        ]
        -dom: null
        -format: null
        -context: null
        #serializer: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer {#1144}
      }
      1 => Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder {#1150 ▶
        #encodingImpl: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncode {#1151 ▶
          -defaultContext: array:1 [▶
            "json_encode_options" => 0
          ]
        }
        #decodingImpl: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonDecode {#1173 ▶
          #serializer: null
          -defaultContext: array:3 [▶
            "json_decode_associative" => true
            "json_decode_options" => 0
            "json_decode_recursion_depth" => 512
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
    #encoderByFormat: []
  }
  #decoder: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\ChainDecoder {#1171 ▶
    #decoders: array:2 [▶
      0 => Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder {#1149 ▶}
      1 => Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder {#1150 ▶}
    ]
    #decoderByFormat: []
  }
  -normalizers: array:1 [▶
    0 => Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer {#1146 ▶
      #defaultContext: array:5 [▶
        "allow_extra_attributes" => true
        "circular_reference_handler" => null
        "circular_reference_limit" => 1
        "ignored_attributes" => []
        "exclude_from_cache_key" => array:1 [▶
          0 => "circular_reference_limit_counters"
        ]
      ]
      #classMetadataFactory: null
      #nameConverter: null
      #serializer: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer {#1144}
      -propertyTypeExtractor: null
      -typesCache: []
      -attributesCache: []
      -objectClassResolver: null
      #classDiscriminatorResolver: null
      #propertyAccessor: Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor {#1147 ▶
        -magicMethodsFlags: 3
        -ignoreInvalidIndices: true
        -ignoreInvalidProperty: false
        -cacheItemPool: null
        -propertyPathCache: []
        -readInfoExtractor: Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor {#1167 ▶
          -mutatorPrefixes: []
          -accessorPrefixes: array:4 [▶
            0 => "get"
            1 => "is"
            2 => "has"
            3 => "can"
          ]
          -arrayMutatorPrefixes: array:2 [▶
            0 => "add"
            1 => "remove"
          ]
          -enableConstructorExtraction: false
          -methodReflectionFlags: 1
          -magicMethodsFlags: 3
          -propertyReflectionFlags: 1
          -inflector: Symfony\Component\String\Inflector\EnglishInflector {#1143}
          -arrayMutatorPrefixesFirst: array:2 [▶
            0 => "add"
            1 => "remove"
          ]
          -arrayMutatorPrefixesLast: array:2 [▶
            0 => "remove"
            1 => "add"
          ]
        }
        -writeInfoExtractor: Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor {#1140 ▶
          -mutatorPrefixes: array:1 [▶
            0 => "set"
          ]
          -accessorPrefixes: array:4 [▶
            0 => "get"
            1 => "is"
            2 => "has"
            3 => "can"
          ]
          -arrayMutatorPrefixes: array:2 [▶
            0 => "add"
            1 => "remove"
          ]
          -enableConstructorExtraction: false
          -methodReflectionFlags: 1
          -magicMethodsFlags: 3
          -propertyReflectionFlags: 1
          -inflector: Symfony\Component\String\Inflector\EnglishInflector {#1141}
          -arrayMutatorPrefixesFirst: array:3 [▶
            0 => "add"
            1 => "remove"
            2 => "set"
          ]
          -arrayMutatorPrefixesLast: array:3 [▶
            0 => "set"
            1 => "remove"
            2 => "add"
          ]
        }
        -readPropertyCache: []
        -writePropertyCache: []
      }
      -discriminatorCache: []
      -objectClassResolver: Closure($class) {#1148 ▶
        class: "Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer"
        this: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer {#1146}
      }
    }
  ]
  -denormalizerCache: []
  -normalizerCache: []
}

Nothing more about the data !!!
The data From Repo is like That...
GrillesController.php on line 79:
App\Entity\Grilles {#796 ▼
  -id: 27
  -email: App\Entity\User {#674 ▶
    -id: 46
    -email: "email@gmail.com"
    -roles: array:1 [▶
      0 => "ROLE_USER"
    ]
    -password: "password"
    -tokenAVerifier: "03cb21ca9"
    -googleId: "16700"
    -avatar: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/7SBolyARBgYgPA53ieFJ8WAJREw=s96-c"
    -hostedDomain: "Google"
    -facebookId: null
  }
  -type: "A"
  -procAge: array:3 [▶
    0 => "12"
    1 => "10"
    2 => "12"
  ]
  -procSexe: array:3 [▶
    0 => "12"
    1 => "13"
    2 => "12"
  ]
  -procCorde: array:8 [▶
    0 => "12"
    1 => "12"
    2 => "12"
    3 => "11"
    4 => "11"
    5 => "10"
    6 => "10"
    7 => "10"
  ]
  -procOeilleres: array:2 [▶
    0 => "12"
    1 => "10"
  ]
  -procFerrage: array:3 [▶
    0 => "2"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "3"
  ]
  -procNbreCourses: array:8 [▶
    0 => "12"
    1 => "12"
    2 => "12"
    3 => "11"
    4 => "11"
    5 => "10"
    6 => "10"
    7 => "10"
  ]
  -procVictoires: array:8 [▶
    0 => "15"
    1 => "14"
    2 => "13"
    3 => "13"
    4 => "12"
    5 => "12"
    6 => "11"
    7 => "10"
  ]
  -procPlaces: array:8 [▶
    0 => "14"
    1 => "14"
    2 => "14"
    3 => "13"
    4 => "12"
    5 => "12"
    6 => "11"
    7 => "10"
  ]
  -procGains: array:8 [▶
    0 => "15"
    1 => "14"
    2 => "13"
    3 => "13"
    4 => "13"
    5 => "12"
    6 => "12"
    7 => "10"
  ]
  -procRapportGainsParCourses: array:8 [▶
    0 => "16"
    1 => "15"
    2 => "14"
    3 => "13"
    4 => "12"
    5 => "11"
    6 => "10"
    7 => "9"
  ]
  -procHandPoids: array:3 [▶
    0 => "14"
    1 => "12"
    2 => "14"
  ]
  -procJockey: array:8 [▶
    0 => "ABRIVARD"
    1 => "RAFFIN"
    2 => "LEBOURGEOIS"
    3 => "THOMAIN"
    4 => "LAGADEUC"
    5 => "GELORMINI"
    6 => "MOTTIER"
    7 => "BEKAERT"
  ]
  -procMusique: array:6 [▶
    0 => "4"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "3"
    3 => "2"
    4 => "2"
    5 => "1"
  ]
  -pointsEntraineur: array:1 [▶
    0 => "null"
  ]
  -pointsJockey: array:1 [▶
    0 => "4"
  ]
  -nomPlat: array:8 [▶
    0 => "OMMEEL"
    1 => "PTIT PEDRO"
    2 => "EL OJANCANO"
    3 => "CAMPELLO"
    4 => "ARDITO"
    5 => "PEARL HARBOUR"
    6 => "BELINSKOV"
    7 => "FILLE DU ROI"
  ]
  -nomTrotAttele: array:8 [▶
    0 => "JUST A GIGOLO"
    1 => "IDAO DE TILLARD"
    2 => "HOHNECK"
    3 => "VIVID WISE AS"
    4 => "ETONNANT"
    5 => "HAPPY AND LUCKY"
    6 => "IDEALE DU CHENE"
    7 => "HOOKER BERRY"
  ]
  -nomHaies: array:8 [▶
    0 => "SUROIT"
    1 => "CAPODIMONTE"
    2 => "CIRANO DE PAIL"
    3 => "JIGTSAR PAM"
    4 => "ICEO MADRIK"
    5 => "FEDOR ROSAY"
    6 => "YOUTWO GLASS"
    7 => "INSIDE MONTLIOUX"
  ]
  -nomTrotMonte: array:8 [▶
    0 => "HONECK"
    1 => "VIVID WISE AS"
    2 => "GRANVILLAISE BLEUE"
    3 => "ETONNANT"
    4 => "JUST A GIGOLO"
    5 => "IDAO DE TILLARD"
    6 => "IZOARD VEDAQUAIS"
    7 => "HOOKER BERRY"
  ]
  -pointsNomPlat: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsNomTrotAttele: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsNomHaies: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsNomTrotMonte: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -entraineursPlat: array:4 [▶
    0 => "GAUVIN"
    1 => "ROUGET"
    2 => "GRAFFARD"
    3 => "REYNIER"
  ]
  -entraineursTrotAttele: array:4 [▶
    0 => "DUVALDESTIN"
    1 => "ABRIVARD"
    2 => "TERRY"
    3 => "GUARATO"
  ]
  -entraineursHaies: array:4 [▶
    0 => "DANIELA MELE"
    1 => "QUINTON"
    2 => "FUIN"
    3 => "COTTIN"
  ]
  -entraineursTrotMonte: array:4 [▶
    0 => "DUVALDESTIN"
    1 => "ABRIVARD"
    2 => "TERRY"
    3 => "GUARATO"
  ]
  -pointsEntraineursPlat: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsEntraineursTrotAttele: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsEntraineursHaies: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsEntraineursTrotMonte: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -proprietairesPlat: array:4 [▶
    0 => "AUGUSTIN-NORMAND"
    1 => "FRASSETTO"
    2 => "CAULLERY"
    3 => "LIBERTY LEAF"
  ]
  -proprietairesTrotAttele: array:4 [▶
    0 => "ALLAIRE"
    1 => "CHARMES"
    2 => "HUNTER VALLEY"
    3 => "BEAUDOUIN"
  ]
  -proprietairesHaies: array:4 [▶
    0 => "AUGUSTIN-NORMAND"
    1 => "FRASSETTO"
    2 => "CAULLERY"
    3 => "LIBERTY LEAF"
  ]
  -proprietairesTrotMonte: array:4 [▶
    0 => "ALLAIRE"
    1 => "CHARMES"
    2 => "HUNTER VALLEY"
    3 => "BEAUDOUIN"
  ]
  -pointsProprietairesPlat: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsProprietairesTrotAttele: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsProprietairesHaies: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -pointsProprietairesTrotMonte: array:1 [▶
    0 => "3"
  ]
  -useNoms: "non"
  -useEntraineurs: "non"
  -useProprietaires: "non"
  -useJockeys: "oui"
  -useDistance: "oui"
  -procRapport: array:8 [▶
    0 => "13"
    1 => "13"
    2 => "13"
    3 => "12"
    4 => "12"
    5 => "12"
    6 => "12"
    7 => "10"
  ]
}

An help will be soon...
Thank you for all...

Ok that's fine I know how to !
The serializer is not the answer about have a not empty return,
Like I see in Symfony 4 - JsonResponse returns a non-empty object as empty
The object Grilles must be transform in array by:
$datas=(array)$datas;

Before return like that a JsonResponse:
 $datas = new JsonResponse($datas);

I add this, if the repository return an array it don't work, must return an object ans convert to an array before return new JsonResponse() (Symfony 5)
